# Inject properties into child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `SkeletonTile` component with an animation where the animation delay can be specified via a passed property.

Example:

```
type Props = {
  delay?: number;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
};

const SkeletonTile: React.FC<Props> = ({ delay, width, height }) => {
  return <div style={{ animationDelay: `${delay}s`, width, height }} className="skeleton-tile"></div>;
}
```

Now, I thought about having a `SkeletonController` component which can take multiple `SkeletonTile` components as children. The `SkeletonController` would then distribute the `delay` values to the child components with increasing delays per child.

Example:

```
<SkeletonController delayIncrease={0.2}>
  <SkeletonTile width="20em" height="20em" />
  <div className="flex">
    <SkeletonTile width="40em" height="20em" />
    <SkeletonTile width="10em" height="20em" />
  </div>
</SkeletonController>
```

So the first `SkeletonTile` would have the delay property set to `0`, the second one to `0.2` and the third one to `0.4`.

I've already tried using the `Children.map` functionality to alter the property values. This is not possible though because property values of components are immutable.

Sure I could use some sort of helper function which creates an array of JSX elements, but then I would lose the option to set different other properties (`width`, `height`) on the children.

Do you have any Idea how this approach would be possible? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of properties to use to create tiles into your controller component:

```
export type TileProps = {
  delay?: number;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
};

const SkeletonTile: React.FC<TileProps> = ({ delay, width, height }) => {
  return <div style={{ animationDelay: `${delay}s`, width, height }} className="skeleton-tile"></div>;
}

type SkeletonProps = {
  tiles: TileProps[];
  delayIncrease: number;
};

const SkeletonController: React.FC<SkeletonProps> = ({ tiles, delayIncrease }) => {
  return tiles.map((tile, index) => (<Tile width={tile.width} height={tile.height} delay={index * delayIncrease} />));
}
```

You can then use your skeleton component like this:

```
const tiles: TileProps[] = [
     { height: '2em', width: '2em' },
     { height: '2em', width: '2em' },
     { height: '2em', width: '2em' },
];

<SkeletonController delayIncrease={0.2} tiles={tiles} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That would at least provide some control, but this would be difficult when I would want to wrap some of the `SkeletonTiles` in sub divs, for example. Should have added that to the question though.